# what is the correct way to create a REST endpoint with relationship

Tags: rest, web-services

I want to create some endpoints to retrieve exceptions per country, startTime and endTime but i don't know what is the correct way to structure the endpoints, i have been talking with my co workers and we have different opinions about how to do it :

**Option 1 Path params**

- **/countries/{countryCode}/exceptions?startTime={value}&endTime={value}**   : To get all the exceptions per country in a certain timeframe
- **/countries/*/exceptions?startTime={value}&endTime={value}**  :To get all the exceptions in a certain timeframe

**Option 2 Query params**

- **/exceptions?country={countryCode}&startTime={value}&endTime={value}** :To get all the exceptions per country in a certain timeframe
- **/exceptions?startTime={value}&endTime={value}**  :To get all the exceptions in a certain timeframe

**Option 3 Path params in a different order**

- **/exceptions/countries/{countryCode}?startTime={value}&endTime={value}** :To get all the exceptions per country in a certain timeframe
- **/exceptions?startTime={value}&endTime={value}**: To get all the exceptions in a certain timeframe

All the 3 options have pros and cons but we don't agree in which is the best practice. The question is what is the best option to create these endpoints.

Answer (score 3):

If the *exception* needs a *country* to exist, that is, the *exception* is a sub resource of *country*, consider:

```
/countries/{countryCode}/exceptions?startTime={value}&endTime={value}
```

Otherwise you can manage the *exceptions* as a separate resource:

```
/exceptions?country={countryCode}&startTime={value}&endTime={value}
```

Comment: but if i choose the first option an exception needs a country to exist but i need 2 endpoints retrieve all the exceptions per country in a time frame and retrieve all the exceptions in a timeframe, how would be the second endpoint ?

Comment: @AlejandroAgapitoBautista The first option of my answer allows you to request all exceptions for a given country. If it doesn't suit you, you may need to manage the exceptions as a separate resource, like in the second option in my answer.

Comment: @AlejandroAgapitoBautista I appreciate the effort and thought you but for maintaining [Semantic URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL). Which is very important when you build an API, which can reach millions. Quite less people give attention to details. 
As most have said and you also have brainstormed, the deciding factor are: 
1. Maintaining the hierarchy and ability to chain/append relation into the current path.
2. Route parameter (Must have params)
3. Query parameter (Optional params)
Been there, hard to pick the best. Better you choose 1 and move-on.

Answer (score 3):

Path parameters should be used when you are displaying a hierarchy, e.g. to show all the comments that respond to the blog with id {id}, you would form this endpoint:

```
/blogs/{id}/comments
```

If you would want to filter these comments base on time, you would use query parameters for that:

```
/blogs/{id}/comments?start={start}&end={end}
```

In your case however, it seems, based on your question, that you have a large list with exceptions. This list can be filtered based on various aspects:

- Country
- Time

Since these properties are not part of the structural hierarchy (based on the context of your question), but simply properties giving more information about the exceptions, it would make sense to catch all them as query parameters to filter on, as such:

```
/exceptions?country={countryCode}&startTime={value}&endTime={value}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option 2** where `Exception` is a separate first-level entity and the endpoint accepts an **optional** country code as a filtering property makes the most sense based on the limited description of your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

It will be hard for you to choose which answer is correct, most answers seem to point out that your *Option 2* is the right choice :)

As far as I'm concerned, what caused me the less troubles with REST architectures was to consider that every resource just have these forms, that return a list (possibly filtered) or a resource:

```
/mainResources
/mainResources/:id
```

And that `/mainResources/:id/:relatedResources` is an alias of
`/relatedResources?mainResourceId[]=...` (returns a filtered list)

Your *option 2* gives you the freedom to add more relations, such as
`/exceptions?country={countryCode}&anotherResource={anotherResourceId}&startTime={value}&endTime={value}`

Your other options are not incompatible if you consider them as aliases.

---

Another reason I can think of to adopt URLs such as `/mainResource/:id/subResource` would be in the case of a denormalized relation such as:

```
{
   'attribute1': 'value1'
   'attribute2': 'value2'
   'attribute3': 'value3'
   'subResource': {
       'attribute4': 'value4',
       'attribute5': 'value5'
   }
}
```

then that kind of URL could return this sub-resource:

```
{
   'attribute4': 'value4',
   'attribute5': 'value5'
}
```

But that's just data filtering. And given your case, storing country exceptions this way wouldn't be convenient.